# What is the relation between IAS and TAS at a constant altitude?

Tags: airspeed

I have noticed that when calculating True Air Speed for any given altitude, the faster the Indicated Air Speed, there seems to be a larger increase in TAS? 
My thinking was that at a constant altitude the relationship between IAS/TAS would be linear, e.g you double IAS, and TAS would double.. But it seems to increase more? Not sure if I'm missing something here?

For example: 
5000ft at 100knts IAS = 114knts TAS
, 5000ft at 110knts IAS = 126knts TAS

Only a couple Knots difference, and it seems to make sense but I can't find any answers on it to confirm it? Would appreciate anybody to shed light on it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you divide 114/100 and 126/110 you'll find the common factor is ~1.14.

Which means for that altitude TAS ≈ 1.14 * IAS.

1.14 is the square root of the ratio of standard sea level [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Atmosphere) air density ($\rho_0$) to the air density at that altitude ($\rho$). This is assuming IAS = [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibrated_airspeed) = [EAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_airspeed) (i.e., ignoring positioning, calibration, and compressibility effects).

The [formula at low-speed flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_airspeed#Low-speed_flight) is:

$$
\text{TAS}
=
\text{EAS}
\sqrt{
\frac{\rho_0}{\rho}
}
$$

---

It looks like you got the numbers from [this](http://indoavis.co.id/main/tas.html) online converter. Note its preset is not a standard ISA, as the altimeter setting reads 28.16 inHg. Instead I recommend [this one](http://www.hochwarth.com/misc/AviationCalculator.html), which is for standard ISA. For 5,000 ft the values are:

```
CAS    TAS
100    107.7
110    118.4
120    129.2
```

With the multiplier at 5,000 feet ISA being ~1.077, and the relation looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Excellent that explains a lot. I first noticed it on my Flight Computer and had to justify that it wasn't miss reading! Thanks for your help.